# Parse header in a file and based on the header replace a value in the file

Tags: bash, shell-script, sed, awk, perl

I have the following file

```
Field1|Field2|Field3|Field4|Field5
a|b|c|d|e
1|2|3|4|5
z|y|x|w|v
```

I have a script which accepts two inputs

```
script.sh Field3 T
```

The script.sh would take the 'Field3' argument and based on that column number should replace the contents with 'T'.

[edit]

I tried the following suggestion from @Costas and ran into a problem.
My file is like this:

```
MODULE_ColumnA~MODULE_ColumnB~MODULE_ColumnC~MODULE_ColumnD~MODULE_ColumnE
8.2~Y~N~~0
```

If I run the following script

```
cat <filename> | awk -F'~' -v p='MODULE_ColumnD' -v r='99' 'NR==1{for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) if($i==p)f=i;print;next}$f=r'
```

It replaces the value, but the delimiter is missing or replaced with space in the output as such:

```
MODULE_ColumnA~MODULE_ColumnB~MODULE_ColumnC~MODULE_ColumnD~MODULE_ColumnE
8.2 Y N 99 0
```

How do I get back the delimiter in the records?

Comment: Why don't you pass `3` instead of `Field3`?

Comment: @cuonglm I just pasted an example to make it simpler to explain, in the actual file, the column headers are named differently and do not have the numeric suffix to them.

Comment: I mean if you pass the column number, it's easier `awk -F'|' -v f=3 -v v=T 'FNR>1{$f=T}1' OFS='|' file`

Comment: @cuonglm Thanks, yes it will make it easier. But the file has about 30 columns, and this script will be used as an utility for other users. So i wanted to make it simpler for them to use.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
awk -F'|' -v p='Field3' -v r='T' '
    NR==1{
        for (i=1;i<=NF;i++)
            if ($i==p)
               f=i
        print
        next}
    $f=r
'
```

If you like to format it to use like `script.awk` save it like:

```
#!/usr/bin/awk -f
BEGIN{
    OFS=FS="|"}
NR==1{
    for (i=1;i<=NF;i++)
        if ($i==p)
            f=i
    print
    next}
$f=r
```

and make its executable by `chmod +x script.awk` and use:

```
./script.awk p=Field4 r=T input.file
```

Comment: I ran into another problem while trying your suggestion. Unfortunately I'm not able to add the explanation as a comment, so I`ve edited my question to include details.

Comment: @rahul If you use variant with `-F'~'` option add `-v OFS='~'` (`O`utput `F`ield `S`eparator)